# What happens if I interrupt a back-up from my laptop to my external hard disk?

Tags: backup

What happens if I interrupt a back-up from my laptop to my external hard disk?  Do I just lose the back-up and have to start over?

Comment: What backup are you referring to? Time Machine?

Answer (score 6):

If it's a Time Machine backup, no, you don't lose your progress if the backup is interrupted. The backup will continue from where it left off. The partial backup is kept in an .inProgress file.